# Draw a program graph over multiple methods

Tags: manual-testing, test-design, testcase

How to draw a program graph similar to but with **multiple methods**?

As it seems the flow of data across methods are not necessarily in the order of declaration.

[image]

**Mulitple Classes**

```
 public class Temp
    {
        //
        private int lowThreshold = 18200; // 1
        private int firstTier = 37000; // 2
        private int firstTierBase = 3572; // 3
 

        public Temp(int income, int age, bool medicareLevy, bool TBRLevy, bool LILevy) // 4
        {
            actualIncome = income - ReturnTax(income, age, medicareLevy, TBRLevy, LILevy); //5
        }
        private double ReturnTax(int income, int age, bool medicareLevy, bool TBRLevy, bool LILevy) // 6
        {
            double stage1 = 0.19; // 7
            double stage2 = 0.325; // 8
            double stage3 = 0.37; // 9
            double stage4 = 0.45; // 10
            double medicareLevyCharge = 0.02;  // 11
            double TBRLevyCharge = 0.02; // 12
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods are isolated blocks of code, with one entry point and many exit points.

If, e.g. on node #11 you had:

```
type = 2;
foo(type);
```

you would draw an arrow from #11 to a special node that represents foo(). The exit of this special node would point to #16.

If the reader of your diagram wants to understand what is inside foo(), he/she can look at another diagram that shows foo() data flow.

Comment: Hi Joao, so the program graph will be drawn based on the order of the execution but not the order of methods/fields declaration?

Comment: Yes, it will depend on what is getting called in each function, not how you organized the functions.